# Take input and use it as range for slicing a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I am trying to do is take 's' as string input and q as integer input.

'x' is a list.

```
s ='abcd'

q = 2
```

input for x:

```
0 2          

1 3
```

desired output:

```
abc

bcd
```

Code:

```
s=input()
q=int(input())
x=list()
for i in range(q):
    x.append(list(map(int,input().split())))
for i,v in enumerate(x):
    for j,z in enumerate(v):
        print(s[v[i]:v[i+1]])
```

Issue:

My output throws error: **index out of range**

```
ab

ab

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/yash/py/substring.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(s[v[i]:v[i+1]]) IndexError: list index out of range:
```

Comment: `print(s[:q+1],s[q-1:])` ?

Comment: What is your question? Does your solution work? If not, how is it deficient?  Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: When asking about code that throws an exception, please post the compleste Traceback, formatted as code.

Comment: You could [catch the exception](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and in the except suite print/inspect relevant data like `i` or `v`. This should give you an idea of what is happening.

Comment: Just a guess... your `i + 1` is giving you the out of range error.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```
s = "abcd"

def slicer(string):

    return string[int(input("Lower bound (inclusive): ")): \
                  int(input("Upper bound (inclusive): ")) + 1]

print("Output: {}".format(slicer(s)))
print("Output: {}".format(slicer(s)))
```

You could also use the `slice()` function.

```
s = "abcd"

def slicer(string):

    return string[slice(int(input("Lower bound (inclusive): ")), \
                        int(input("Upper bound (inclusive): ")) + 1)]

print("Output: {}".format(slicer(s)))
print("Output: {}".format(slicer(s)))
```

Both cases will return a `list` sliced from the user entered lower bound up to and including the user entered upper bound.

Output sample:

```
Lower bound (inclusive): 0
Upper bound (inclusive): 2
Output: abc
Lower bound (inclusive): 1
Upper bound (inclusive): 3
Output: bcd
```

Comment: Did you mean to hard code `s` there? Shouldn't that be `string` inside your function?